# require() returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Hi.

I've been on this for a while now, and cannot figure out why my dynamic module loader does not load files correctly. It simply just returns an empty object for every file.

```
function loadCommands() {
   require('fs').readdirSync(require('path').join(__dirname, 'commands')).forEach(file => {
       let commandName = file.substring(0, file.length - 3); // this removes the .js extension off of the file.
       commands[commandName] = require('./commands/' + file);
   });
}
```

This code should load each file in the ./commands directory and put it in an object called commands.

The require() function returns an empty object.

A sample command file contains the following:

```
const Command = require('../Command');

class Ban extends Command {
    constructor(options) {
        this.description = 'Bans a user.';
    }
    execute() {

    }
}

module.exports = Ban;
```

Command contains the following:

```
class Command {
    constructor() {
        this.description = 'unknown';
    }
    execute() {

    }
}

module.exports = Command;
```

If I do commands["ban"], it returns an empty object instead of the class I was expecting.

I am really confused onto what is going on here, as there's no circular dependencies at all.

If anyone can help me, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not needed. I already fill in all the information in the constructor. And either way, is off topic and not related to the question.

Comment: Yup. Double checked before posting.

Comment: Then, `require('./commands/' + file);` must not be looking in the right place or your modules contain an error?

Comment: Are you using webPack or any other bundler?  Some bundlers do not allow computed file names with `require()`.

Comment: Reply to comment 1: super() doesn't affect. Still returns empty object. Reply to comment 2: It is looking in the right place. Reply to comment 3: No bundlers, plain node.js

Comment: Well, if loading/running your code causes an error, then that could be one reason why you don't get your modules loaded properly.  Just looking for things that could be wrong in your code to cause what you observe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160743/discussion-between-lewistehminerz-and-jfriend00).

Comment: Do your modules run at all?  If you put `console.log("inside Command")` inside of the Command module, does it output?

Comment: Yes. But we should stop using comments and use chat.

Comment: I have nothing else to add.  You seem to have reported that everything works except the final result.  Nothing else I can do without having something to actually debug.  My next step would be to step through the loading of the files in the debugger and see what's actually getting assigned to `commands` object.

Comment: When I tried to recreate these three files and run it, I got an error on this line `const Command = require('../command');` until I changed it to `const Command = require('./command');`.  Note entirely sure I had the exact same file structure, but it seems to be the file structure that your `readdirSync()` requires (class files all in a sub-directory named `command`).

Comment: At which moment do you call `loadCommands()`? What does an explicit `require('./commands/ban')` give you? This could be an issue with circular dependencies...